# Arithmetic expression evaluation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, operators, evaluation, operator-precedence

Here i am trying to evaluate the expression in Haskell using defined values of `Exp` data type. The function type would be `eval :: Exp -> Int` and data type is this:

```
data Exp = Num Int
       | Exp :+: Exp
       | Exp :-: Exp
       | Exp :*: Exp
       | Exp :/: Exp
       deriving (Show)
```

and values which i am trying to evaluate are these:

```
 4 + 5 * 6 , respecting correct precedences of the operators
 4 + 5 + 6 , respecting, that + binds left-associative
 (4 + 3) * (5 - 2)
 4 + (4 / (2 - 2))
```

So far this logic is working fine which is:

```
eval :: Exp -> Int
eval (Num a) = a 
eval (a :+: b) = (eval a) + (eval b)
eval (a :-: b) = (eval a) - (eval b)
eval (a :*: b) = (eval a) * (eval b)
eval (a :/: b) = (eval a) `div` (eval b)
```

When i pass this i get `3` as output which is correct:

```
eval (Num 2 :+: Num 2 :-: Num 1) 
output = 3
```

but i am confused how it evaluated the second part of the expression which `:-:` what i understood the only pattern matched in first iteration was `eval (a :+: b) = (eval a) + (eval b)` which returned `4` as output how it carries `4` to next iteration to perform the `:-:` operation?

before that i was trying something like this:

```
eval :: Exp -> Int
eval (Num a) = a
eval (Num a :+: Num b) = eval (Num a) + eval (Num b)
eval (Num a :-: Num b) = eval (Num a) - eval (Num b)
eval (Num a :*: Num b) = eval (Num a) * eval (Num b)
eval (Num a :/: Num b) = eval (Num a) `div` eval (Num b)
```

it didn't give the desired results and then i just changed it to the first version. it worked fine but didn't get the proper semantics of it. Any help? Please don't hesitate to go into details. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The default fixity for operators is [`infixl 9`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html) (see `4.4.2  Fixity Declarations`).

You have not declared the fixity for your `:+:` etc. operators.

This means that your expression gets parsed as

```
eval ((Num 2 :+: Num 2) :-: Num 1)  :: Exp

--     Num 2                        :: Exp 
--               Num 2              :: Exp 
--     Num 2 :+: Num 2              :: Exp 
--                          Num 1   :: Exp 
--    (Num 2 :+: Num 2) :-: Num 1   :: Exp
```

So the evaluation proceeded as

```
  eval ((Num 2 :+: Num 2) :-: Num 1)  -- match with:
  eval (a                 :-: b    ) = (eval a) - (eval b)
                                     =  ....
```

Comment: Thanks it actually helped.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in other answers, the problem is that all your constructors have the same default precedence: they are left-associative with high (9) precedence. You can change that using the `infixl` directive.

```
data Exp = Num Int
       | Exp :+: Exp
       | Exp :-: Exp
       | Exp :*: Exp
       | Exp :/: Exp
       deriving (Show)

-- Using the same precedences as (+), (-), (*), and (/)
infixl 6 :+:, :-:
infixl 7 :*:, :/:
```

Now `eval $ Num 4 :+: Num 2 :*: Num 3` will correctly return 10 instead of 18.

Comment: Thanks, everyone i understood what is explained above. but one thing is still confusing how does Haskell identified value constructors (:+:) as operators or is this the default behavior with every value constructor? Usually we position value constructor right after `=` then values. ?

Comment: A (non-alphabetic) data constructor that starts with `:` is infix by default. The simplest one is `:` itself, which is why you usually write `1 : [2,3,4]` instead of `(:) 1 [2,3,4]`. `Num 3 :+: Num 4` is equivalent to `(:+:) (Num 3) (Num 4)`

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to follow what's going on here is just to follow the evaluation through one step at a time. Since as @WillNess has explained the default order of operation is from left to right, your code is evaluated as follows (each individual step comes directly from one of the lines of your definitioni of `eval`):

```
eval ((Num 2 :+: Num 2) :-: Num 1)
eval (Num 2 :+: Num 2) - eval(Num 1)
(eval (Num 2 :+: Num 2)) - 1
(eval (Num 2) + eval (Num 2)) - 1
(2 + 2) - 1
4 - 1
3
```

I hope this makes it clear.